# Azure MySQL In App for web app not updating rows

Tags: php, database, azure, mysqli

I copied my entire folder to the web app via `ftp` the page loads without any problems, I'm using a `config.php` file in the `config/` folder:

```
<?php
 $host = '127.0.0.1';
 $username = '-';
 $password = '-';
 $db_name = 'localdb';

//Establishes the connection
 $link = mysqli_init();
 mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 49187);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
  die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Close the connection
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The link works because if I go to the `index.php` page with the wrong details filled in on the connection bit the page won't even load, I also tried to see if I could create a table in this file:

```
<?php
 $host = '127.0.0.1';
 $username = '-';
 $password = '-';
 $db_name = 'localdb';

//Establishes the connection
 $link = mysqli_init();
 mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $username, $password, $db_name, 49187);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
  die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

 if (mysqli_query($link, '
 CREATE TABLE test (
 `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `test1` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
 `test2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `test3` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
 );
 ')) {
 printf("Table created\n");
}

//Close the connection
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

This works too, when navigating to the `index.php` on the top left corner you can see `Table created`.

I exported the database I was using and imported it to the current database, this all works, the connection isn't the issue.

so on the `index.php` page the log in code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){
    header("location: dashboard.php");
}

require_once "config/config.php";

$email = $password = "";
$email_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please enter your email address.";
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if(empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)){

        $sql = "SELECT id, email, password FROM members WHERE email = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_email);

            $param_email = $email;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $email, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                        session_start();

                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["email"] = $email;

                            header("location: dashboard.php");
                        } else{
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    $email_err = "No account found with that email.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Why I'm so confused is because nothing but

```
 $host = '127.0.0.1';
 $username = '-';
 $password = '-';
 $db_name = 'localdb';
```

These details have changed.

Comment: `updating rows`, but __where__ is the update query?

Comment: Sorry with `updating rows` I mean `SELECT` `UPDATE` `INSERT` etc, it worked on my old website, without any issues but since I moved to azure for some reason the imported data from my old db to the new one it doesn't work.

With the create table in my `config.php` file it did create a new table and I also created rows, deleted them without any issue but the `members` and `servers` table don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a blog post on using MySQL in-app that may be of help.  Emphasis was the original author's.

---

As a **BEST PRACTICE** when using MySQL in-app, we recommend to ALWAYS use Environment variables for the database information to prevent database connection issues with your web app. If your application requires a separate variable for port , you can use `WEBSITE_MYSQL_PORT` environment variable. The port number selected can vary if the instance is recycled and hence *ALWAYS use environment variables*.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/